# what is wrong with the sql lite connection string?

Tags: sqlite

very new to sql lite,

I want to use it for a small project, get some overview, and try to implement but i got error while use following connection string?

Can some one please tell me what is wrong and what changes i need to do when i will set the path from web.config for sql lite connection string.

```
 SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("D:\\Projects\\Apica MVC\\wizardDemo\\Apica.Signupweb.Presentation.MvcWeb\\App_Data\\SignUpWebDB");
```

i got an error.......

"Invalid ConnectionString format for parameter "D:\Projects\Apica MVC\wizardDemo\Apica.Signupweb.Presentation.MvcWeb\App_Data\SignUpWebDB""

There is no password set for string.

Comment: Is this C#, C++ or something else?

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite this site may help

Answer (score 17):

Your connection string isn't correctly formatted.

You're specifying the full path and filename of the database file, but you need to ensure that you include the `Data source=` part of the connection string in front of the actual database path and filename (also notice the semi-colon at the end of the connection string before the closing quote).

For example:

```
SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=D:\\Projects\\Apica MVC\\wizardDemo\\Apica.Signupweb.Presentation.MvcWeb\\App_Data\\SignUpWebDB;");
```

There are more parameters that you can specify within a SQLite Connection string, see [this link](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/p/938/9942.aspx) from the old System.Data.SQLite forums for further information.  The complete documentation for the System.Data.SQLite package can be found at [this page](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki).  The [source code file](http://system.data.sqlite.org/sqlite-netFx-source-1.0.77.0.zip) (amongst others) contains the SQLite.NET.chm documentation file.